# Trace to Console in MFC application

Tags: c++, mfc, console, app-config, trace

I am currently tracing my errors in an MFC application to a .log file and to the event viewer, but I would also like to trace to the console. A console solution is posted here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/612/Creating-a-console-for-your-MFC-app-s-debug-output

but I want to be able to turn it on and off easily (Perhaps with a TraceSwitch).

Comment: *app-config* refers to a .NET application configuration file. Are you looking for a managed or unmanaged solution?

Comment: I am trying to use the configuration file to instantiate a Console Trace Listener, then in a C# dll I will use Trace.WriteLIne

Comment: Then I am confused about the *mfc* tag. How is MFC related here?

Comment: The MFC application is the GUI which runs the code. If the code has an error, I would like to trace the error to the Console and to a Log File.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the obvious,

```
<add name="LPRConsoleListener" type=System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" />
```

You must put

```
AllocConsole()
```

in your InitInstance() function before you initialize your MFC Window.